# Rails - getting values from a model into the application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model

I'm wanting to get the 'current_item.quantity' from a model for use in a view - i.e. I want to be able to put '(x) items currently in your cart' in the application layout view. How would I go about doing this? Have tried every combination of '@total_current_items' etc. that I can think of. Thanks!!

Here's the model code if it helps:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

def add_product(product_id)
  current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
  if current_item
    current_item.quantity += 1
  else
    current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
    current_item.price = current_item.product.price
  end
  current_item
end

def total_price
  line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
end

def decrease(line_item_id)
  current_item = line_items.find(line_item_id)
  if current_item.quantity > 1
    current_item.quantity -= 1
  else
    current_item.destroy
  end
  current_item
end

def increase(line_item_id)
  current_item = line_items.find(line_item_id)
  current_item.quantity += 1
  current_item
end
end
```

As requested, here is the view code (relevant portion):

```
<% if @cart %>
<%= hidden_div_if(@cart.line_items.empty?, id:'cart') do %>
<div class="row-fluid">
        <a class="btn btn-success menu" id="menubutton" href="<%= cart_path(session[:cart_id]) %>">View Cart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid"> 
                You have <%= pluralize(@total_current_items, "item") %>in your cart.    
                </div>

                <% end %>           
            <% end %>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I've tried putting the following in the application helper, but it's not working. It either comes up with an undefined method/variable error message, or says 'You have 0 items in your cart', even when there are items in there. I've tried putting @total_items, total_items etc. to reference it in the view, but I'm new to rails and don't know what to do to get it to work!

```
 def total_items
   @line_items = LineItem.find(params[:id])
   @total_items = @line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_quantity}
 end
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: show what you have tried in the application layout

Comment: What you want to do is get a list/array of all the items in your cart. Then you can look up how to get the number of items i.e. count an array contains.

Comment: @Nobita I've added the application layout now.

Comment: @Mark - How would I go about doing this? I apologise, I'm new to rails, so not familiar how to do it! Thanks!

Comment: Where do you set @total_current_items?

Comment: As @Nobita has pointed out you will have to show us the code where you assign total_current_items. It will probably be in the controller.
Have a look at ActiveRecord where syntax which allows you to get an array of items from a model.

Comment: @Mark the code I'm trying to reference is in the above model - it's the 'current_item.quantity' value that I want. How would I reference this in the application view? Thanks!

Comment: @Nobita I've added the view code above, as well as my attempt at referencing it in the application layout view. If you could help point out where I'm going wrong, it would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Nils pointed out you have to assign `@total_current_items` (in your controller) so you can access it. Now looking at your view code I guess you have the information present in the `@cart`.

The member variable `@cart` (member variable because it has an `@`) is assigned in your controller. You can access member variables assigned in the controller also in your views.

You want to find out how many line_items are attached to the cart. You are already checking if any line_items are in the cart (else you won't display what you want to achieve). So instead of checking your array if it's empty. Try getting the length of the array i.e. the number of line_items currently present in your cart.

Comment: This is the application layout - so would I still be able to access a member variable assigned in a seperate controller?

Comment: I've tried adding the code to the application helper, but with no success. I've put what I've tried above, but can't get it to work - if you can point out where I'm going wrong, I'd be very grateful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, but comments can't really have code blocks:

You should put the code to assign the `@code` and `total_current_items` in `ApplicationController` as a protected method. Then use it as a before_filter, so that the method will run before *every* controller (page)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :get_cart    

  protected
  def get_cart
    @cart = SOMETHING
    @total_current_items = SOMETHING
  end
end
```

before_filter - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `total_current_items` in your controller for it to be available in your view.

Same goes for `cart` if that isn't set either.

Comment: how would I go about doing this? I've put my attempt above - I've put it in the application helper as I'm trying to make it available to the application layout view - is that the right place? I can't get it to work, so any help you can give would be great, thanks!